# c# to VB translation of declaring Arrays

Tags: vb.net

This should be an easy thing to do but my brain is not working

In C# I can have the following:

```
SqlParameter[] spParameter 
spParameter = new SqlParameter[3];
```

How do I this in VB

```
Dim Params() As SqlParameter
Params = New SqlParameter(4) //<- This line does not work because 
                             //    SqlParameter has a constructor
```

So how do I actually create the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the squiggly braces:

```
Dim spParameter As SqlParameter()
spParameter = New SqlParameter(2) {}
```

Comment: that is the key.  Thank you, I miss c#

Comment: You might find http://converter.telerik.com/ useful in that case. I use it when I need to quickly convert something I know in `C#` into it's `VB.NET` equivalent

Answer (score 1):

Put the index in the type:

```
Dim Params(2) As SqlParameter
```

Note that C# uses the length, while VB uses the highest index, so 3 in C# corresponds to 2 in VB.

Comment: I should have clarified I wanted to do it in two steps because the 4 in the example is dynamic

Answer (score 1):

Dim Params(3) As SqlParameter

Params(0) = New SqlParameter()

Params(1) = New SqlParameter()

Params(2) = New SqlParameter()